# TinyMCE on Textarea

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, tinymce

I am developing a discussion panel in ASP.NET in which my [TinyMCE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TinyMCE) code is the following:

```html
<!-- TinyMCE -->

<script type="text/javascript" src="tinymce/jscripts/tiny_mce/tiny_mce.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    tinyMCE.init({
        // General options
        mode: "textareas",
        theme: "advanced",
        editor_selector : "mceEditor",

        element: "abc",

        plugins: "pagebreak,style,layer,table,save,advhr,advimage,advlink,emotions,iespell,inlinepopups,insertdatetime,preview,media,searchreplace,print,contextmenu,paste,directionality,fullscreen,noneditable,visualchars,nonbreaking,xhtmlxtras,template,wordcount,advlist,autosave",

        setup: function (ed) {
            ed.onKeyPress.add(
                function (ed, evt) {

                }
            );
        },

        // Theme options
        theme_advanced_buttons1: "save,newdocument,|,bold,italic,underline,strikethrough,|,justifyleft,justifycenter,justifyright,justifyfull,styleselect,formatselect,fontselect,fontsizeselect",
        theme_advanced_buttons2: "cut,copy,paste,pastetext,pasteword,|,search,replace,|,bullist,numlist,|,outdent,indent,blockquote,|,undo,redo,|,link,unlink,anchor,image,cleanup,help,code,|,insertdate,inserttime,preview,|,forecolor,backcolor",
        theme_advanced_buttons3: "tablecontrols,|,hr,removeformat,visualaid,|,sub,sup,|,charmap,emotions,iespell,media,advhr,|,print,|,ltr,rtl,|,fullscreen",
        theme_advanced_buttons4: "insertlayer,moveforward,movebackward,absolute,|,styleprops,|,cite,abbr,acronym,del,ins,attribs,|,visualchars,nonbreaking,template,pagebreak,restoredraft",
        theme_advanced_toolbar_location: "top",
        theme_advanced_toolbar_align: "left",
        theme_advanced_statusbar_location: "bottom",
        theme_advanced_resizing: true,

        // Example content CSS (should be your site CSS)
        content_css: "css/content.css",

        // Drop lists for link/image/media/template dialogs
        template_external_list_url: "lists/template_list.js",
        external_link_list_url: "lists/link_list.js",
        external_image_list_url: "lists/image_list.js",
        media_external_list_url: "lists/media_list.js",

        // Style formats
        style_formats: [
            { title: 'Bold text', inline: 'b' },
            { title: 'Red text', inline: 'span', styles: { color: '#ff0000'} },
            { title: 'Red header', block: 'h1', styles: { color: '#ff0000'} },
            { title: 'Example 1', inline: 'span', classes: 'example1' },
            { title: 'Example 2', inline: 'span', classes: 'example2' },
            { title: 'Table styles' },
            { title: 'Table row 1', selector: 'tr', classes: 'tablerow1' }
        ],

        // Replace values for the template plugin
        template_replace_values: {
            username: "Some User",
            staffid: "991234"
        }
    });
</script>

<!-- /TinyMCE -->
```

I want to apply the TinyMCE editor on the text area and in my HTML I am giving the text area with the class name:

```
<% using (Html.BeginForm("PostProblem", "Discussion", FormMethod.Post))
    { %>

        <textarea id = "abc" class =  "mceEditor" rows = "100" cols = "100" ></textarea>

    <% } %>
```

The textarea is not working. It is showing a simple textarea, not a TinyMCE text area :(

Comment: make sure the script appears ***before*** the `textarea` you want to replace - as everything you've posted looks fine... *What errors are you receiving on your page*?

Comment: Simple textarea apears...make sure the script appears before the textarea you want to replace ? plz explain it.

Comment: the `tincymce` script needs to appear *before* in the `HTML` that contains the `textarea`
...

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the path for *tiny_mce.js* is correct. Better choose it (*tinymce/jscripts/tiny_mce/tiny_mce.js*).

Verify also if your textarea looks fine without <% ...%> sections, and also remove class property for the moment, just to identify which one is the cause...